Как можно получить кол-во квартир в определенной области используя открытое API Yandex карт?
(Если нужно покупать доступ к апи, то все равно интересно как это реализовать)
Смысл в том, чтобы примерно определить населенность разных частей города. Я хочу взять с api данные о том, сколько квартир в этой области (от заданной точки радиусом от 100м до 1км) и показать их. Пожалуйста помогите!!

из яндекса берёте адрес дома, из фиас - все его квартиры.  фиас бесплатный

Под вашу задачу у нас нет готовых публичных API. Сервисы не предназначены для выгрузки каталогов, и получить количество квартир в заданном полигоне нашими инструментами невозможно.
